# How can I find where a linux elf executable found and satisfied external references

Tags: linker, external, symbols, elf

I would like to find the location of where an external referenced from a linux elf executable found and resolved that reference.  Let's say I have possibly an object file, and one or more libraries that define a symbol of the same name.  How can I tell which one was used by the linker to resolve that reference.
Specifically, I'm trying to determine if there were any externals from a specific library used to satisfy external references by that program.  I realize that I could just drop the library from the link directive, but there will be some routines that I will need from that library, I'm looking for ojects of a specific name.

Answer (score 1):

From ld --help

> ```
> --cref
> ```
>
> Output a cross reference table. If a linker map file is being generated, the cross reference table is printed to the map file.
> Otherwise, it is printed on the standard output. The format of the
> table is intentionally simple, so that it may be easily processed by a
> script if necessary. The symbols are printed out, sorted by name. For
> each symbol, a list of file names is given. If the symbol is defined,
> the first file listed is the location of the definition. The remaining
> files contain references to the symbol.

and

> -M
> --print-map
> Print a link map to the standard output. A link map provides information about the link, including the following:
>
> - Where object files and symbols are mapped into memory.
> - How common symbols are allocated.
> - All archive members included in the link, with a mention of the symbol which caused the archive member to be brought in.